# Spring MVC REST - Block access to Web Methods

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have this method in my Controller that returns a json string to the view

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDevs", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public@ResponseBody String getDevs() throws JsonProcessingException,RemoteException,ServiceException{

    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    return om.writeValueAsString(WSCall.getDevelopers());
}
```

I call the method URL using ajax. Everything works fine except I can obtain the json if I put the URL directly in the browser. Is there a way to block this?

Comment: Why would access via the browser be special in any way?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. I don't know if accessing the method directly in the browser and getting the info can be considered a security issue in an application. That's why I'm trying to prevent it.

Comment: The web browser is a client like every other client. It has a better GUI than `curl`, but nothing more. Your AJAX calls can be watched in the browser’s developer tools anyway, so there is not much point in hiding.

Comment: The only idea that came in mind is to use the accept type. But this will not really block the request, it will make it only harder to access the controller

Comment: So, is it OK to leave it that way? Also, access to those URL can be controlled with Spring Security right? I mean user control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments above, that it is not relevant from a security standpoint, but you could probably make use of the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header that is most likely set for your AJAX requests. I can at least confirm it for jQuery, which might be on your tool stack.

So you could add the headers parameter to your `@RequestMapping` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDevs", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers = { "X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest" })
public@ResponseBody String getDevs() throws JsonProcessingException,RemoteException,ServiceException{
  [...]
}
```